# Measure purity of a function

Tags: javascript, testing, functional-programming

Is there an existing solution to detect if a function is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) or impure, or the degree of purity using some metrics?

The case is, I want to transition my existing app code to more functional-style, and one of the desires is to reduce the impurity of functions to the bare minimum level. I can do it manually, but if can be automated, why not?

I know [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) can be measured with tools like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity.html), so I think purity can be too.

Comment: I suppose you could use a definition of pure like "has no observable side effects" and then define side effects as memory accesses outside of a function's stack frame - so using the heap or accessing memory that isn't local. Offhand, detecting whether a variable references local scope or not sounds like it would be undecidable in general; but you could probably measure via profiling or debugging how the algorithm performs in certain test cases. As far as metrics - maybe number of non-local-scope memory writes per statement executed? Lower is "more" pure.

Comment: Note - while computing this may be undecidable in general, you can definitely still use heuristics to estimate it, or design it in such a way that you can produce a valid proof that the metric adds up to some number or other. I just don't think you're going to be able to algorithmically answer the question, "Does this function alter non-local memory?" That's almost certainly equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: Not sure, but would sth like this be of any use? `var r = Reflect (src); r.findType ('Identifier').flatten ().forEach (function (token) {
  var eR = token.envRec;
  if (eR.DEF.length < 1 || token.DEF && ( token.block !== eR.scope () || eR.DEF [0].parent.value === 'function')) token.parentByType ("Function").impure = true
})`

Which would basicallly mean: Parse the `src`, filter Identifiers, flatten the AST, iterate over result. If an Identifier is part of an assignment, check if its definition is in another scope. If so, the function containing it will be marked impure.

Comment: This comes with some caveats though. You won't be able to catch dynamic references like `foo [bar]` or `eval ('foo="asd"')` obviously. Also I'm still far from finishing this, so the parser might be not complete. I only tested with jQuery and angular so far

Comment: [Detecting Function Purity in JavaScript](ftp://soft.vub.ac.be/tech_report/2015/vub-soft-tr-15-09.pdf) is a paper that was published literally the same month you asked the question.  I'm afraid purity in JavaScript seems some way off becoming a commodity.